# Problems with transparency when creating a texture from a mixture of textures with SDL_2?

Tags: transparency, sdl-2

I am trying to create a texture from several textures, but it seems that I have a problem setting the transparency:

```
SDL_Texture *backgr = SDL_CreateTexture(render, 
                        SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888, 
                        SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET, 
                        width, 
                        height);`<br/>

//After this line, the texture is rendered black
SDL_SetAlphaMod(backgr, 0);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod gives the same result

Answer (score 2):

You need to set blend mode as well to enable Alpha-blending.

```
SDL_SetTextureBlendMode( backgr , SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND );
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the migration guide for SDL2 you shouldn't use `SDL_SetAlphaMod` with SDL2 but rather [SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod) (or `SDL_SetSurfaceAlphaMod`for surfaces). If you need an example on how to use it check out the [tutorial by Lazy Foo](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/13_alpha_blending/index.php).